# Wpf custom control

Tags: wpf, controls

I have a customn control which display a window with another custom control inside. The developper can redefine the control template, it works but I don't find a way to allow developper to redefine the template of control inside the window that the custom control display...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found. The solution is simply to set the other control as a dependency property inside the first (parent) control...